# 'trash:' vs 'trash:/'

Tags: kubuntu, trash

A accidentally removed the Trash icon from dolphin, and created a new one, typing 'trash:' for the location. But when I clicked on it it would show the trash folder, but the 'Empty Trash' menu entry on the context menu was grayed out.

When I changed the location to 'trash:/', it started working correctly, and 'Empty Trash' was not grayed out anymore.

So Why is there a difference between 'trash:' and 'trash:/'?

Answer (score 1):

**trash:/**

The "trash:/" is a KDE kioslave. Here is a "A Quick and Easy Guide to KDE KIO slaves": http://maketecheasier.com/quick-easy-guide-to-kde-kio-slaves/2009/08/17